# transition not working for gradiant filling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, css-transitions

css transition properly work for normal SVG path color filling with jQuery as follows.

```
path
{
margin-top: 25px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 1.8s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1.8s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1.8s ease;
-o-transition: all 1.8s ease;
transition: all 1.8s ease;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(event.target).css('fill', '#000');
```

But path filling using radial-gradiant filling transition not working.

```
<radialGradient id="MyGradient"><stop offset="5%" stop-color="#f60"></stop><stop offset="95%" stop-color="#ff6"></stop></radialGradient>
```

jQuery

```
$(event.target).css('fill', 'url(#MyGradient)');
```

Why this happens? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> "Just like you can’t smoothly transition from one background image to
>   another, you can’t smoothly transition from one CSS gradient to
>   another. It’s binary; either one background-image is shown or the
>   other."

Background gradient transitions are not really supported. There are work arounds and hacks, but for the most part you wont be able to make the transition using standard methods. I would recommend reading this article on medium for possible solutions (which is where the above quote is from).

https://medium.com/@dave_lunny/animating-css-gradients-using-only-css-d2fd7671e759

EDIT: In the case of SVG's you will need to use the `<animate>` tag within the SVG. See this demo for usage of that within and SVG: https://designmodo.com/demo/svg-gradients/

Comment: CSS transitions work also for SVG, you don't *need* to use [SMIL](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#RelationshipToSMILAnimation) syntax except in cases where an attribute is not defined as a [presentation attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#UsingPresentationAttributes).

Answer (score 0):

What would be the continuous transition between one [paint](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) **name** and another? What lies haflway between `url(#MyGradient)` and `#000`?

You can only define transitions in a meaningfull way between numeric values of the same attribute. Colors, described as numeric representations of the three RGB channels also count as numbers (as long as you don't use named colors).

For radial gradients, you can transition `stop-color` or `stop-opacity` values. `offset` or the cx, cy, fx, fy, r values of the gradient dimensions can be animated using the [SMIL animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html) syntax.